# PrimeFaces fileUpload testing with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, primefaces, selenium-webdriver

I've successfully tested fileUploadSimple http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSimple.jsf
with webElement.sendKeys() method. It doesn't work with Auto upload

Is there any way to test PrimeFaces fileUploadAuto http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadAuto.jsf with Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: what do you want to assert within the test?

Comment: I assert that that byte array of uploaded image equals to byte array of actual image. Official site states for fileUploadAuto component the following: "When auto upload is enabled, upload process begins once the file is selected".

Answer (score 5):

I also have like your development. I am going to share my knowledge but there might a better way.

jsf-code at servier side

```
<h:form id="lifeProposalEntryForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{AddNewLifeProposalActionBean.handleProposalAttachment}"  
            mode="advanced" multiple="true" sizeLimit="3000000" update="customerEntryPanel attachmentDataList"
            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" id="proposalAttachment"/>    
</h:form>
```

html-code at client side

```
<div id="lifeProposalEntryForm:proposalAttachment" class="ui-fileupload ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-fileupload-buttonbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-top">
        <span class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-fileupload-choose" role="button">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-plusthick"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Choose</span>
            <input id="lifeProposalEntryForm:proposalAttachment_input" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="lifeProposalEntryForm:proposalAttachment_input">
        </span>
        <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-fileupload-upload" type="button" role="button">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-n"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Upload</span>
        </button>
        <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-fileupload-cancel" type="button" role="button">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-cancel"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Cancel</span>
        </button>
    </div>
......
```

- Retrieve the element of `lifeProposalEntryForm:proposalAttachment_input` by `id`.
- Put/sendkey the file (one or more files)
- Retrieve the element of `second button` of `<div id="lifeProposalEntryForm:proposalAttachment"`.
- Click the button element.

Selinium Testing in java

```
webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("lifeProposalEntryForm:proposalAttachment_input"));
webElement.sendKeys("C:\\temp\\life\\life_1.jpg");
webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file'and @id='lifeProposalEntryForm:proposalAttachment_input']"));
webElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lifeProposalEntryForm:proposalAttachment']/div[1]/button[1]"));
webElement.click();
```

Try as I mention. It is work for me.