# Why can I click an input with type=radio of a h:selectOneRadio, but not one of a p:selectOneRadio with Graphene/Selenium?

Tags: selenium, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, graphene2

A `h:selectOneRadio` results in `<input type="radio">` in a table and `p:selectOneRadio` in `<input type="radio">` in a table with some `div`s around the `input`. The id for both is `[form id]:[selectOneRadio id]:[option number]` which I can use successfully for the plain JSF in a Graphene functional test when accessing it with `@FindBy(id="[...]")` whereas the PrimeFaces variant fails due to `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException`. Investigating the generated HTML I don't see the difference

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/34696ceb-eeaa-4b35-88dd-f3c8fc5901bf/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/34696ceb-eeaa-4b35-88dd-f3c8fc5901bf/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml;jsessionid=48ca919d0b7e89661f92149ac321?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/34696ceb-eeaa-4b35-88dd-f3c8fc5901bf/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml;jsessionid=48ca919d0b7e89661f92149ac321?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/34696ceb-eeaa-4b35-88dd-f3c8fc5901bf/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml;jsessionid=48ca919d0b7e89661f92149ac321?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0"></script>
  <title>Facelet Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" method="post" action="/34696ceb-eeaa-4b35-88dd-f3c8fc5901bf/index.xhtml;jsessionid=48ca919d0b7e89661f92149ac321" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input name="mainForm" value="mainForm" type="hidden">
    <table id="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadio">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadio" id="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadio:0" value="a" type="radio">
            <label for="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadio:0"> a</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadio" id="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadio:1" value="b" type="radio">
            <label for="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadio:1"> b</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadio" id="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadio:2" value="c" type="radio">
            <label for="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadio:2"> c</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime" class="ui-selectoneradio ui-widget">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
              <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                <input id="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime:0" name="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime" value="aPrime" type="radio">
              </div>
              <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-radiobutton-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime:0">aPrime</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
              <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                <input id="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime:1" name="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime" value="bPrime" type="radio">
              </div>
              <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-radiobutton-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime:1">bPrime</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
              <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                <input id="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime:2" name="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime" value="cPrime" type="radio">
              </div>
              <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-radiobutton-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label for="mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime:2">cPrime</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="-485558793831512050:990657069126697889" autocomplete="off" type="hidden">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

nor do I if I deploy the application on Payara 4.1.2 or any other reason for the `ElementNotInteractableException`.

The access is done with

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyManagedBeanTest {
    private static final String WEBAPP_SRC = "src/main/webapp";
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyManagedBeanTest.class);

    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment0() throws TransformerException, XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        WebArchive retValue = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .add(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                .addClasses(MyManagedBean.class)
                .addAsWebInfResource(
                        new StringAsset("<faces-config version=\"2.0\"/>"),
                        "faces-config.xml");
        Maven.configureResolver().workOffline().resolve("richtercloud:graphene-click-input-radio:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT").withoutTransitivity().asList(JavaArchive.class).forEach(dependency -> retValue.addAsLibrary(dependency));
        //add all webapp resources
        retValue.merge(ShrinkWrap.create(GenericArchive.class)
                .as(ExplodedImporter.class)
                .importDirectory(WEBAPP_SRC)
                .as(GenericArchive.class), "/", Filters.include(".*\\.(xhtml|css|js|png)$"));

        ByteArrayOutputStream archiveContentOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        retValue.writeTo(archiveContentOutputStream, Formatters.VERBOSE);
        LOGGER.info(archiveContentOutputStream.toString());
        return retValue;
    }

    @Drone
    private WebDriver browser;
    @ArquillianResource
    private URL deploymentUrl;
    @FindBy(id = "mainForm:mainSelectOneRadio:0")
    private WebElement mainSelectOneRadioOption0;
    @FindBy(id = "mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime:0")
    private WebElement mainSelectOneRadioPrimeOption0;

    @Test
    public void testAll() {
        browser.get(deploymentUrl.toExternalForm()+"index.xhtml");
        LOGGER.debug(browser.getPageSource());
        mainSelectOneRadioOption0.click();
        mainSelectOneRadioPrimeOption0.click();
    }
}
```

I'm searching for a solution which triggers JSF action methods and AJAX listeners!

I'd be interested in a generic approach as well, e.g. `p:selectOneButton` produces

```
<div id="mainForm:mainSelectOneButtonPrime" class="ui-selectonebutton ui-buttonset ui-widget ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left">
        <input id="mainForm:mainSelectOneButtonPrime:0" name="mainForm:mainSelectOneButtonPrime" value="aPrime" class="ui-helper-hidden" type="radio">
        <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">aPrime</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only">
        <input id="mainForm:mainSelectOneButtonPrime:1" name="mainForm:mainSelectOneButtonPrime" value="bPrime" class="ui-helper-hidden" type="radio">
        <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">bPrime</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-right">
        <input id="mainForm:mainSelectOneButtonPrime:2" name="mainForm:mainSelectOneButtonPrime" value="cPrime" class="ui-helper-hidden" type="radio">
        <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">cPrime</span>
    </div>
</div>
<input name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="-5130093024933213812:2291815208147638618" autocomplete="off" type="hidden">
```

which doesn't seem to have anything in common with the HTML generated for `p:selectOneRadio` at first sight. Maybe there's a trick.

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.1.

Comment: Sure you click on the right elements? With PF ypu need to click om different things than with plain jsf since the orininal inputs are wrapped...

Comment: There're only `div`s and `input`s involved and only clicking on `input` makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean the element with `id = "mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime:0"`?

Comment: @Guy the generated HTML element with the id `mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime:0` is the one I want to click on programmatically in the functional test. It's represented by `mainSelectOneRadioPrimeOption0` in the code above afaik.

Comment: If you have thought on improving the testability of PrimeFaces, don't hesitate to contribute at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765542/how-to-access-primefaces-components-through-graphene-in-the-most-portable-way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Guy has the right answer.

The issue here is that PrimeFaces is applying its own styling on top of the HTML which is covering the element you are trying to click.

Selenium checks that the targeted element `mainForm:mainSelectOneRadio:0` receives the events when the element on top is clicked. But in this case the overlay is done with a sibling container which is not an descendant of targeted element. Thus Selenium assumes that the element will not receive the events and raises an `ElementNotInteractableException` (see [event bubbling and propagation](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)).

You can clearly see the issue by visiting [oneRadio.xhtml](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml) and by inspecting the radio button with a right click. You'll see that the selected DOM element and the `<input>` are located in two different branches of the DOM tree.

To overcome this issue, either click the label since it has no overlay (see solution from @Guy). The label has the `for` attribute which mean that all the events are forwarded to the element assigned to `for` which is the targeted `<input>`.

You could also directly click the overlay. Though, you'll have to use an XPath to express the relationship.

Parent of parent of the targeted `<input>` :

```
    @FindBy(xpath = "id('mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime:2')/../..")  
    private WebElement mainSelectOneRadioPrimeOption0;
```

Or first `<td>` having the targeted `<input>` :

```
    @FindBy(xpath = "//td[.//input[@id='mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime:2']]")
    private WebElement mainSelectOneRadioPrimeOption0;
```

Comment: Thanks for this good answer. It'll improve my understanding of Selenium beyond the scope of this question. It's unfortunate that there's no library/extension wrapping all this logic and allowing to do `PrimeFacesSelectOneRadio (extends WebElement).getSelectedOption()`. See comment on Guy's answer about the distribution of points.

Answer (score 4):

`ui-helper-hidden-accessible` is a [JQuery](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.11/theming/css-framework/) layout helper to hide items visually. The radio button you see is actually the parent element, `<div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">`.

The problem can be resolved by clicking on the radio button label. The 'for` attribute [put the focus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12894185/5168011) on the input label [associated with it](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp)

```
@FindBy(css = "[for='mainForm:mainSelectOneRadioPrime:0']")
private WebElement mainSelectOneRadioPrimeOption0;
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Any change you could give me a hint how click on an option produced by `f:selectItems` inside a `p:selectOneButton`. The generated HTML doesn't contain `label`s.

Comment: I figured it out based on the answer by FlorentB.: `@FindBy(xpath = "id('mainForm:mainSelectOneButtonPrime:0')/../span")`. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I'll probably give the bounty to you and the correct answer to Florent B. since his explanation helped me a lot as well - your answer is correct as well, it's only about the points I have to give.

Comment: @KarlRichter `@FindBy(css = "[id='mainForm:mainSelectOneButtonPrime:1'] + span")` should also work