# How to check a p:selectBooleanCheckbox and wait for it to be checked in Graphene/Selenium?

Tags: selenium, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, graphene2

Similar to [Why can I click an input with type=radio of a h:selectOneRadio, but not one of a p:selectOneRadio with Graphene/Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47106401/why-can-i-click-an-input-with-type-radio-of-a-hselectoneradio-but-not-one-of-a) I'd like to know how I can check a `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` in a functional tests with Arquillian and Selenium/Graphene and wait for it to be checked.

I already figured out

- that in plain HTML the checked state is determined not by the value of the `checked` attribute, but by its presence and that in XHTML (where the attribute needs to be always present) by the value `checked` (not `true` or `false`, but why make a new standard intuitive...), see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp for details.
- that the Selenium documentation can be misleading in some cases (I'd say even wrong) since it doesn't distinguish between `""` and `null` for example in some cases, like `ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(WebElement, String, String)` and doesn't mention it - and then the request to improve it get closed with a hint that the [Javadoc is accepted to be wrong because everything is well documented in the W3C web driver spec](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5649).
- that `WebElement.click` (where the `WebElement` instance refers to the id of `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` works in a minimal environment, but not in a complex one.

The checkbox is checked when I investigate visually with Firefox after the checkbox is clicked with `WebElement.click` on the `@FindBy(id="mainForm:mainCheckbox")` element declared in JSF:

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="mainCheckbox"
                             value="#{managedBeanView.property0}"/>
</h:form>
```

I tried:

- to investigate the `checked` attribute of the generated `div` which simply always is present (or maybe not, see trouble with Selenium documentation above)
- wait for the `checked` attribute of the nested HTML `_input` which never the attribute `checked` apparently (or maybe not, see above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the pretty awesome [arquillian-primefaces project](https://github.com/omnifaces/arquillian-primefaces) now which provides a one-liner. In case you can't use this:

```
/**
 * Checks a {@code p:selectBooleanCheckbox} and waits for it to be checked.
 * The method works for XHTML elements only and does not check whether the
 * passed {@code checkbox} is declared in XHTML.
 *
 * The handling of Primefaces in functional testing with Selenium/Graphene
 * is extremely difficult because the behaviour of elements is not
 * documented in a usable way (either extremely complex for Primefaces
 * developers or not at all), so that the following behaviour has been
 * extracted:<ul>
 * <li>The checked state of HTML input element which is a checkbox is
 * determined by the presence of the {@code checked} attribute and not its
 * value. In XHTML where the attribute has to be always present its the
 * value {@code checked} of the attribute .See
 * {@link https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp} for details.
 * </li>
 * <li>The {@code checked} attribute on {@code checkbox} is always
 * {@code null} and
 * {@code ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(checkbox, "checked", "")} is
 * always {@code true} (Selenium doesn't document whether it distinguishes
 * between {@code ""} and {@code null} and refused all suggestions on
 * improving the documentation (see e.g.
 * https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5649)).</li>
 * <li>{@link WebElement#click() } works in a minimal environment (the
 * checked state appears visually) whereas it doesn't work in most real
 * world conditions.</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * Asked
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765542/how-to-access-primefaces-components-through-graphene-in-the-most-portable-way
 * for a general solution.
 *
 * @param browser the web driver to use
 * @param checkbox the web element representing the {@code p:selectBooleanCheckbox}
 * @param checked whether to check or uncheck the checkbox
 */
public void checkCheckbox(WebDriver browser,
        WebElement checkbox,
        boolean checked) {
    assert checkbox.getAttribute("id") != null
            && !checkbox.getAttribute("id").isEmpty();
    String checkboxInputId = String.format("%s_input",
            checkbox.getAttribute("id"));
    final WebElement checkboxInputElement = checkbox.findElements(By.xpath(String.format("id('%s')/div[2]/span",
                    checkbox.getAttribute("id"))))
            .stream().collect(MoreCollectors.onlyElement());
    if(checked && !isCheckboxChecked(browser, checkboxInputId)
            || !checked && isCheckboxChecked(browser, checkboxInputId)) {
        LOGGER.trace("checkCheckbox: need to click");
        LOGGER.trace(String.format("checkboxInputElement.selected: %s",
                isCheckboxChecked(browser, checkboxInputId)));
        checkboxInputElement.click();
        LOGGER.trace(String.format("checkboxInputElement.selected: %s",
                isCheckboxChecked(browser, checkboxInputId)));
        //- cannot invoke `checkboxInputElement.click` because the element
        //is not visible
        //- cannot invoke `checkboxInputElement.isSelected` or
        //`checkbox.isSelected` (causes
        //org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotSelectableException)
    }
    new WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
        (WebDriver t) -> {
            boolean retValue0 = isCheckboxChecked(browser,
                    checkboxInputId) == checked;
            return retValue0;
        });
        //waiting for the checked attribute is no guarantee that the check
        //will be visible on the screenshot
}

private boolean isCheckboxChecked(WebDriver browser,
        String checkboxInputId) {
    boolean retValue = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)browser).executeScript(String.format("return document.getElementById('%s').checked;",
                    checkboxInputId));
    return retValue;
}
```

I figured out the right elements using the Selenium IDE which will probably help in all other similar situations.